# how to disable button(onclick javascript) after clicking that once?

Tags: custom-button

I created that button and by clicking it is redirecting to the readonly page.This is my code which I have written in detail page button,content source is Onclick javascript.

Now I want to disable the 'Close ' button after clicking it once.For that I wrote a vf page and put that link here but it's going to vf page after clicking close button.

How to disable this button ?

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}
fuction validate()
{
var oppObj = new sforce.SObject("Open_Selection__c"); 
oppObj.Id = '{!Open_Selection__c.Id}'; 
oppObj.Status__c = "Closed";
oppObj.RecordTypeId = '0126F000001YdAb'; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([oppObj]); 

if (result[0].success=='false') {
     alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {
     location.reload(true);



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is placed on Standard Record Detail page then this button will always be available and cannot be disabled.

Though you can show an alert based on the `Closed` status as follows:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}
fuction validate()
{
    var oppObj = new sforce.SObject("Open_Selection__c"); 
    oppObj.Id = '{!Open_Selection__c.Id}'; 
    if('{!Open_Selection__c.Status__c}' == "Closed")
    {
        alert("Status is already closed. You cannot make any changes");     
    }
    else
    {
        oppObj.Status__c = "Closed";
        oppObj.RecordTypeId = '0126F000001YdAb'; 
        var result = sforce.connection.update([oppObj]); 

        if (result[0].success=='false') {
             alert(result[0].errors.message);
        } else {
             location.reload(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Santanu Boral.Here I am getting another error while clicking the button..It's showing Invalid RecordType because I have set the master RecordType to my profile and I want to change the recordtype when the button has been clicked.For that I have used oppObj.RecordTypeId = '0126F000001YdAb'; This is the custom RecordType Id..How to resolve this error...

Comment: Basically you should have access to the recordtype which you are setting. In the profile, add the recordtype. Also, here, in the code dont hardcode recordtypeId.

Comment: If i will add the recordtype in profile then while creating new record for the object it's taking the custom recordtype as default and i don't want that..

Comment: check this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_recordtype.htm&type=5